# Make only part of a html anchor clickable

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, i18next

I'm looking for something like this

```
<p>This website is&nbsp;<a href="{github/link}">open source</a>. Made by ...</p>
```

But having all the text in one same tag/line and specify the link with css or javascript or maybe an even better html usage. I'm in react if that changes anything.

The reason I want to do this is because I am using i18next, to create a multilingual website and if I have 3 text elements (before, link and after) I unnecessarily need 3 entries to my translation json file, which when scaling up is impractical and also screams bad practice.

Think about the text as an incoming variable that needs to filter out the text to select as a link. I can only think of really dirty javascript ways of doing it, ideally I'm looking for a reusable solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Is Markdown an option for you? Your line could then be written as `This website is [open source](https://github.com/...). Made by...` and translated as a single string

Comment: Sometimes is better leave things as is. Maybe simpler use a key like myLink1, myLink2 and myLink3 in the JSON. Or use a single entry including the link with some text to replace with the translated url

Comment: if you’re using react, have a look at the Trans component: https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component

Comment: Unfortunately, markdown is not an option for me @AdamTaylor as I want to add a target="_blank" prop.

Comment: Thanks @adrai! Worked a charm, definitely the best way to do it.